# In Oracle - ALTER TABLE can I cascade data type changes?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I have a parent table (ParentId) and a child (ParentId,ChildId) table. ParentId in the parent table is defined as VARCHAR2 ( 25 characters ) and so is ParentId in the child table. I want to change the data type to VARCHAR2 ( 50 characters ) . Can I do it in such a way that this change is cascaded to the Child table ?

Cheers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  There is no way to cascade the changes.  (Well, there might be some obscure way if you had defined your columns based on the same user-defined type but that would undoubtedly create more issues than it would solve).  You'd need to issue one `ALTER` for the parent and one for the child table.

If you have a more complicated schema where you're trying to trace changes from a parent table through many child and grandchild tables, you could use the data dictionary to walk the hierarchy.  Here is [one query to return the table hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872486/populate-test-data-to-oracle-database/5872821#5872821) based on one of Frank Kulash's [OTN Forums posts](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/667943).  If the column is named the same in every table, you can do something even easier and just query `dba_tab_columns` for all the columns with that name and a `data_length` of 25 rather than 50.